# PHP Regex / Yii2 Pattern allow alphabet, numeric, space and some symbol / special character

Tags: php, regex, yii2

I've a text field for Job Position in my form, and I need to add validation like this:

1. Deny symbol exc: `-`, `,`, `.`, and `/`
2. Allow alphabet, numeric, and space

I've add like this in **modal.php**

```
'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z.,-]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z.,-]+)*$/'
```

It's almost work well, it's reject `/` and numeric.

Anyone can fix my pattern above, so it can work like my requierments above.

Thanks

Comment: Obviously! `/` and digits aren't in your character classes. Add them.

Comment: Yeah,I'm sure about that. Can you fix that and give a little learn about regex? thanks

Comment: You can have a little learn if you take the time to read a basic tutorial about regex, I can't do it for you.

Comment: Yeah I see, but I'm really in deadline. But, it's your right. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Did the provided solution work?

Comment: it's work :D thankyou @mega6382

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.,\-\/\s]+$/
```

This will allow numbers, aplhabets, spaces `/`, `-`, `.` and `,` and nothing else.

And you can learn more about regex from here https://regexone.com

Comment: Hi my friend, I got an issue :( I got this preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found

Comment: it's didn't work well. It didn't show `preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found` but it also allow all special character.

Comment: @Blackjack Can you provide an example string, I'll be sure to check it.

Comment: This one `I have 2 banana$, an'd on\e a/p-pl"e`

Comment: Try the following then `/^[a-zA-Z0-9.,\-\/\s]+$/`